# SQL – How to get the total per day, not split out by the GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I have a table structured like this:

```
day         Item    Buyer_id
19/10/2022  Shoes   58423401
19/10/2022  Shoes   58423402
19/10/2022  Bikes   58423403
19/10/2022  Shoes   58423404
20/10/2022  Bikes   58423405
20/10/2022  Shoes   58423406
```

I need display my data like this: In the column on the right, I would like to sum up all sales of that day. This is my desired result, grouped by items:

```
Day         Item     number_of_buyers    total_number_of_buyers_per_day
19/10/2022  Shoes    5,000               55,000
19/10/2022  Bikes    50,000              55,000
20/10/2022  Shoes    45,000              95,000
20/10/2022  Bikes    50,000              95,000
```

However, this is what I keep getting:

```
Day         Item     number_of_buyers   total_number_of_buyers_per_day
19/10/2022  Shoes    5,000              5,000 
19/10/2022  Bikes    50,000             50,000 
20/10/2022  Shoes    45,000             45,000 
20/10/2022  Bikes    50,000             50,000
```

What I have done so far is this: I tried to get the number of total buyers into my last column with a join.

```
SELECT 
        a.day
        , a.item
        , COUNT (DISTINCT a.buyer_id) AS number_of_buyers
        , COUNT(b.number_of_total_users_on_site) AS total_number_of_buyers_per_day

FROM 
        buyers

LEFT JOIN
       (
        SELECT day, COUNT (DISTINCT buyer_id) AS number_of_total_buyers
        FROM buyers
        GROUP BY 1, 2
        ORDER BY 1, 2
        ) AS b 
        ON a.buyer_id = b.buyer_id 
        AND a.day = b.day 
 
GROUP BY 
        1, 2 
 
ORDER BY 
        1, 2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: i am wondering gow you reach the number_of_buyers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a global solution. In some rdbms you can `count(distinct)` inside a window function and that would make it simpler.

```
select   day
        ,item
        ,count(distinct buyer_id)                                  as number_of_buyers
        ,sum(count(distinct_buyers_by_day)) over(partition by day) as total_number_of_buyers_per_day
from 
(
select   day
        ,item
        ,buyer_id
        ,case when buyer_id != lag(buyer_id) over(partition by day order by buyer_id) or lag(buyer_id) over(partition by day order by buyer_id) is null then 1 end as distinct_buyers_by_day
from     t
) t
group by day, item
```

| day | item | number_of_buyers | total_number_of_buyers_per_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-19 | Bikes | 1 | 4 |
| 2022-10-19 | Shoes | 3 | 4 |
| 2022-10-20 | Bikes | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-10-20 | Shoes | 1 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HEPrk-91)